# Handlebars helper i18n

Tags: ember.js, internationalization, ember-i18n

If I'm using an Ember.js built in helper `input`

```
{{input value=query class="form-input" placeholder="Search"}}
```

I want to replace the placeholder string "Search" with a translated version of that string.

Normally, if I wasn't already using the `input` helper, I would access the translated string like this:

```
{{ t "home.search" }}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured this out by using Subexpressions: http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html

```
{{input value=query class="form-input" placeholder=(t "home.search") }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get dylanjha's solution to work because Ember.I18n's t helper returns a span wrapped around the translated text, not the translated text itself. I solved this by writing my own helper that invokes the translation directly:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ts', function (key) {
  return Em.I18n.t(key);
});
```

I then was able to use my helper like this:

```
{{input value=login placeholder=(ts 'signin.login') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my app:

```
// This is a custom text field that allows i18n placeholders
App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['autofocus', 'z-index', 'autocomplete'],

    placeholder: function () {
        if (this.get('placeholderKey')) {
            return I18n.t(this.get('placeholderKey'));
        } else {
            return ''; //or this.get('placeholder')
        }
    }.property('placeholderKey')
});
```